# ASP.NET Core : connect to Active Directory using Kerberos and Novell.Directory.Ldap.NETStandard library

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, active-directory, ldap, novell

I have a .NET Core application that runs in a Linux environment and I have fetched some data from Active Directory and the authentication should be done using Kerberos. To accomplish that I have tried two packages that work perfectly but only in Windows and they don't work on Linux, those packages are:

```
System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement 
system.DirectoryServices.Protocols
```

I started looking into an alternatives including Novell, but after reading the documentation I found out that it doesn't support Kerberos auth.

Do you have any information or reliable solution to connect to Active Directory with Kerberos using a package that runs in a Linux environment?